# understanding Has A relationship implementation C#

Tags: c#, associations, relationship

My point is, `aPerson.PhoneNumber.Number` is a string, so it should take the string type value.

Again, in the code, `aPerson.PhoneNumber = phoneNumber` both `aPerson.PhoneNumber` and `phoneNumber` are `PersonPhoneNumber` type object.

What actually changed after the line that

```
aPerson.PhoneNumber.Number = "Test Phone";
```

worked?

Can anyone please tell me why those two lines show error during compiling?

```
class PersonPhoneNumber
{
    public string Number { get; set; }
}

class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public PersonPhoneNumber PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Person aPerson = new Person();
        aPerson.Name = "Test Name";

        aPerson.PhoneNumber.Number = "Test Phone";//Error: System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

        PersonPhoneNumber phoneNumber = new PersonPhoneNumber();

        aPerson.PhoneNumber.Number = "Test Phone";//Error: System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

        aPerson.PhoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        aPerson.PhoneNumber.Number = "Test Phone"; // This does not show any error

        Console.WriteLine(aPerson.Name);
        Console.WriteLine(aPerson.PhoneNumber.Number);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, I don't think you mean error during compiling, but rather during runtime.

Your problem is that aPerson.PhoneNumber is null for the first 2 attempts to set Number property. It's not until you set `aPerson.PhoneNumber = phoneNumber` that it's no longer null. So the error is pretty clear.

Answer (score 1):

If you want `aPerson.PhoneNumber.Number = "Test Phone";` to work as shown in your code, you will have to initialize your `aPerson.PhoneNumber` first.

This is commonly done in the constructor of your `Person` class:

```
public class Person
{
    public Person()
    {
        this.PhoneNumber = new PersonPhoneNumber();
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public PersonPhoneNumber PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Disclaimer: This will only solve to error you get - it is not good practice in general.